# Measuring time: differences among gettimeofday, TSC and clock ticks

Tags: linux, performance, profiling, intel, rdtsc

I am doing some performance profiling for part of my program. And I try to measure the execution with the following four methods. Interestingly they show different results and I don't fully understand their differences. My CPU is Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770. System is Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks in advance for any explanation.

Method 1:
Use the `gettimeofday()` function, result is in seconds

Method 2:
Use the `rdtsc` instruction similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/14019158/3721062

Method 3 and 4 exploits Intel's [Performance Counter Monitor](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-performance-counter-monitor-a-better-way-to-measure-cpu-utilization)  (PCM) API

Method 3:
Use PCM's

`uint64 getCycles(const CounterStateType & before, const CounterStateType &after)`

Its description (I don't quite understand):

```
Computes the number core clock cycles when signal on a specific core is running (not halted)

Returns number of used cycles (halted cyles are not counted). The counter does not advance in the following conditions:

an ACPI C-state is other than C0 for normal operation
HLT
STPCLK+ pin is asserted
being throttled by TM1
during the frequency switching phase of a performance state transition
The performance counter for this event counts across performance state transitions using different core clock frequencies
```

Method 4:
Use PCM's

`uint64 getInvariantTSC (const CounterStateType & before, const CounterStateType & after)`

Its description:

```
Computes number of invariant time stamp counter ticks.

This counter counts irrespectively of C-, P- or T-states
```

Two samples runs generate result as follows:
(Method 1 is in seconds. Methods 2~4 are divided by a (same) number to show a per-item cost).

```
0.016489 0.533603 0.588103 4.15136 

0.020374 0.659265 0.730308 5.15672
```

Some observations:

1. The ratio of Method 1 over Method 2 is very consistent, while the others are not. i.e., 0.016489/0.533603 = 0.020374/0.659265. Assuming `gettimeofday()` is sufficiently accurate, the `rdtsc` method exhibits the "invariant" property. (Yep I read from Internet that current generation of Intel CPU has this feature for `rdtsc`.)
2. Methods 3 reports higher than Method 2. I guess its somehow different from the TSC. But what is it?
3. Methods 4 is the most confusing one. It reports an order of magnitude larger number than Methods 2 and 3. Shouldn't it be also kind of cycle counts? Let alone it carries the "Invariant" name.

Comment: Is this for Linux? If so please tag it as such. Or .Net or Android or ...

Comment: @RenniePet Oh I forgot the most important information. This is for Linux. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Answer (score 1):

`gettimeofday()` is not designed for measuring time intervals. Don't use it for that purpose.

If you need wall time intervals, use the POSIX monotonic clock. If you need CPU time spent by a particular process or thread, use the POSIX process time or thread time clocks. See `man clock_gettime`.

PCM API is great for fine tuned performance measurement when you know exactly what you are doing. Which is generally obtaining a variety of separate memory, core, cache, low-power, ... performance figures. Don't start messing with it if you are not sure what exact services you need from it that you can't get from `clock_gettime`.

Comment: If I do want to get the wall time interval, but in terms of cycles/ticks, is there a method to get it?

Comment: I'm looking at PCM because I want to profile some L2CacheMiss, L2CacheHitRatio ... Stuff. But I got stuck just when starting by the timing functions.

Comment: I'm not sure "tick" has any reliable meaning. Your CPU clock frequency may be variable, and the kernel may be tickless etc.

Comment: Yes, if you want cache profiling and the like, then PCM is the way to go.